# Relation between SVD and POD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

I understand that POD is about choosing an optimal base, and i have found this Eckart Young theorem
[image: Eckart Theorem]

And also have encountered on a book that given an matrix $A$ its projection on POD modes is given by $U^TAU$ where $U$ is given by the SVD decomposition $A=U\Sigma V^T$.

But i don't see the correlation on why should $U$ be the projection.

Ps: This projection is a low-rank structure

Comment: What does POD stand for?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom proper orthogonal decomposition, also related to PCA

Comment: Is there a difference between PCA and POD?  Also, I don't know what you mean by "$U$ should be the projection"